# Are there Humainoid robots in Altered Carbon?

Tags: altered-carbon

In the series *[Altered Carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon_(TV_series))* which takes place in the future, I see examples of perfect AIs (e.g. Poe), but I don't recall any humanoid robots of any kind to be seen in the first season.

- If there was an example and I missed it, point me to where to look again.
- If there wasn't any as I'm assuming, why is that so? Why wouldn't they put up an AI on a machine? Did I miss something or is it just not explained anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't recall any humanoid robots of any kind

### There were (kinda) but they looked like people.

They were called **Synths**

> Synthetic humans, or “synths,” are biorobotic androids that provide a cheaper alternative to resleeving in a human body. If you can’t afford a new sleeve, you can download your DHF into a synth.  Synths are also used by sex workers and other people looking for a disposable sleeve.
>
> Sleeving into a synth is physically jarring, as the nerve responses are only approximations of human sensation, and things like taste and smell are severely blunted or entirely absent.
>
> <sup>[Wikia](http://netflixsalteredcarbon.wikia.com/wiki/Basic_Terms_and_Concepts)</sup>

This becomes a plot point later when

> Lizzie Elliott (the murdered daughter) uploads herself into a synth body when they take down "Head in the Clouds".

---

As for why there are no autonomous robots with AI onboard, you will recall that humans have a deep distrust of AI due to their *quirks*.

The Raven Hotel had not had a guest for 50 years.

Also, the AI don't really seem to want to interact with humans (Poe seems to be an exception) but rather take advantage of them but investing in their respective outlets for their vices.